# Generalization of classified raster: reassigning class after Region Group and Nibble

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, classification

I want to do a Generalization of classified raster in ArcGIS as it is described here: [Generalization of classified raster imagery](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/generalization-of-classified-raster-imagery.htm). The documentation includes following steps: 1. Majority Filter, 2. Boundary Clean, 3. Region Group, 4. Extract small regions, 5. Eliminating small regions with Nibble.

It works fine until the Nibble step. I used the output of the Region Grouping as input raster and the output of the extraction as raster mask in the Nibble step.
The Region Group step creates a Classify.pixel value, which counts the created regions and a Classify.Class value, which still contains the class. In the attribute table the class is stored in a LINK column. The nibble tool uses the Classify.pixel value.
The output of the nibble tool doesn't have a LINK column anymore. It looses the class information. The documentation says at the end "Using the link item from the results of the Region Group tool, the original zone values from the classified image are reassigned to the individual regions created from the Region Group tool".

How can I reassign the original zone values to the individual regions?